# Angular UI Router root named view template change from child view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Setup is using Angular v1.5.8, and ui-router v0.3.1 . My root view has several named sections (ive removed a number of them for brevity). It looks like this

```
<section id="container">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="overlay">
            <section id="overlay__content" ui-view="overlay"></section>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <section id="content__content" ui-view="content"></section>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

My state controller looks like this

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app',{
        url: '/',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'overlay': {
                templateUrl: partialsUrl + 'main.overlay.html', // <-- content below
                controller: 'OverlayController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.foo', {
        url: 'foo',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: partialsUrl + 'foo.main.html',
                controller: 'FooController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.foo.add', {
        url: '/add',
        views:{
            'content@overlay':{ // <-- DOES NOT WORK
                templateUrl: partialsUrl + 'foo.add.html',
                controller: 'FooAddController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    })
```

My overlay view template (`main.overlay.html`) looks like this

```
<a class="close">&times;</a>
<div ui-view="content"></div> <!-- <-- LOAD CONTENT INTO HERE -->
```

What Im trying to do is when the `app.foo.add` state is initiated to load content into the `content` section of the `overlay` root named view. I can access the root content view using `content@` successfully as [described here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views). However, there doesnt seem to be any documentation about traversing into a states's view deeply. Ideally i would imagine i would want something like `content@app(overview)` (assuming that `()` allowed you to select a named view and then go into it, or perhaps `content@app@overview`. Neither of which work.

Any suggestions for a solution or something fundamental that im missing would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've interpreted your problem correctly, then I think this should work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('app', ['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider){
        $stateProvider
          .state('app', {
            url: '/',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
              'overlay': {
                templateUrl: 'overlay.html'
              }
            }
          })
          .state('app.foo', {
            url: 'foo',
            views: {
              'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'foo.content.html'
              }
            }
          })
          .state('app.foo.add', {
            url: '/add',
            views: {
              'content@app': {
                templateUrl: 'foo.add.content.html'
              }
            }
          });
      }).run(function($state){
        $state.go('app.foo.add');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ui-view="overlay">

    </div>
    <div ui-view="content">

    </div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="overlay.html">
      <h1>Overlay</h1>
      <div ui-view="content"></div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="foo.content.html">
      <h1>Foo Content</h1>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="foo.add.content.html">
      <h1>Foo Add Content</h1>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### Explanation

I think the misunderstanding you have is what the symbol after the `@` stands for. The symbol before the `@` is the name of the view you want to match, and the symbol after the `@` is a reference to the state in which the template the ui-view directive should exist in.

So in this example, `content@app` is saying look for `ui-view="content"` inside any of the views inside the `app` state.

Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: Ah, I hadnt realised that it would search through "any of the views", made some minor changes to my code (updated the view name to avoid collisions) and it is working, Thank you

Comment: No problems. Yeah i was just going to say you should probably not call everything `content`

Comment: that makes sense now that i know they are deeply traversable :P