# angular uirouter opens wrong url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, jhipster

I'm new to Angular 1 and have to implement a new feature on an existing webapp. The app uses jhipster to generate some parts of the backend and frontend (Angular 1 and uirouter).

So I tried to use my own route and `state` like this which is mostly copy and pasted from existing components of the webapp:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('artemisApp')
        .config(stateConfig);

    stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

  function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('model-comparison-exercise-for-course', {
        parent: 'entity',
        url: '/course/{courseid}/model-comparison-exercise',
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_TA'],
            pageTitle: 'artemisApp.modelComparisonExercise.home.title'
        },
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/entities/model-comparison-exercise/model-comparison-exercise.html',
                controller: 'ModelComparisonExerciseController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                $translatePartialLoader.addPart('modelComparisonExercise');
                $translatePartialLoader.addPart('exercise');
                $translatePartialLoader.addPart('global');
                return $translate.refresh();
            }],
            courseEntity: ['$stateParams', 'Course', function ($stateParams, Course) {
                return Course.get({id: $stateParams.courseid}).$promise;
            }]
        }
    });
}

})();
```

Then I try to open this route with the following code:

```
<a ui-sref="model-comparison-exercise-for-course({courseid:course.id})"
   data-translate="artemisApp.course.modelComparisonExercises"></a>
```

By clicking on that link a http get request is fired which returns a http status code 404: http://localhost:8080/app/entities/model-comparison-exercise/model-comparison-exercise.html

Actually, the url that should be opened is `http://localhost:8080/#/course/1/model-comparison-exercise`

Any idea what I could have configured wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try changing `'content@'` to `'content@artemisApp'`.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114835/angular-ui-router-root-named-view-template-change-from-child-view):

> The symbol before the @ is the name of the view you want to match, and the symbol after the @ is a reference to the state in which the template the ui-view directive should exist in.

And the `<a>` tag is not being closed:

```
<a ui-sref="model-comparison-exercise-for-course({courseid:course.id})"
   data-translate="artemisApp.course.modelComparisonExercises"></a>
```

Searching through the code, I found that `model-comparison-exercise.html` does not exist in folder `model-comparison-exercise`. Besides `model-comparison-exercises.html` exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't fix my problem. Also all existing components of this webapp also just use  `content@` and it is working fine there. The component I have to add is basically the same as one of the existing, I just have to change minor UI things. As already said, here also `content@` works fine. Any other idea?

Comment: And just saw you are missing closing the `a` tag.

Comment: oops, seems like I have removed the closing `a` during code formatting on stackoverflow. So the whole code of my project can be found here: https://github.com/ls1intum/ArTEMiS/tree/hd/umleditor/src/main/webapp/app and here is my component: https://github.com/ls1intum/ArTEMiS/tree/hd/umleditor/src/main/webapp/app/entities/model-comparison-exercise

The other component that works can be found here: https://github.com/ls1intum/ArTEMiS/tree/hd/umleditor/src/main/webapp/app/entities/programming-exercise

Comment: Sorry for the delay (probably different timezones issue). Searching through the code, I found that `model-comparison-exercise.html` does not exist in folder `model-comparison-exercise`. Besides `model-comparison-exercises.html` exist. Please have a look.

Comment: oh man, you are right, that was the problem. I'm really sorry for bothering you. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. I am pretty sure you would figured it out, sooner or later. Sometimes, a second eye just helps. :)